# Push Notification TabBar Does not appear

Tags: ios, swift, push

In `didReceiveRemoteNotification` I have

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "RAV", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AdvanceViewController") as! AdvanceViewController
window?.rootViewController = vc
```

Inside the app when I navigate to `AdvanceViewController` the tabBar works, but when I'm open by push, it does not appear.

The Push Works, what does not work it's tabBar

Does anyone know how to do fix it?

Comment: Do you get any error or it does not show up anything ?

Comment: "Inside the app when I navigate to AdvanceViewController the tabBar works, but when I'm open by push, it does not appear.": what do you mean by that? What is your expected behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tab bar does not display because you instantiated the view which lies in the tab bar as the root view controller, but that would mean that it is the root controller now, not the tabbar (but you want the tabbar to be the root view controller). What you need to do is set the root view controller to the tab bar and then set the tab bar to the correct index.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I got to fix this problem